# Magento 2 Load/Set Custom Customer Attribute

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2.1, customer-attribute

I've create a customer attribute, when the attribute is set I can change its value etc, however when the attribute is not set it doesn't show up therefore I can not set it. Is there a way to do this?

I am currently loading the`\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` and loading the customer by its ID.

Comment: Tried to re-index database?

Comment: Yes I have reindexed